# Sort values in array with awk

Tags: awk, gawk

This script works fine for me. It is able to email the owner of one or more locks and show him/her the list of locks s/he is holding.

However, I would like the file paths to be sorted alphanumerically. I tried using `print owner | "sort"` but the result looks strange.

I pass this into the script: `svnadmin lslocks $SVN_REPO /Trunk | locks.awk`

```
#!/bin/gawk
BEGIN {
    # RS="" means "record separator is a blank line"
    RS=""
    FS="\n"
    counter=0
    # number of days (seconds) for an old lock
    THRESHOLD_DAYS      =   7
    THRESHOLD_SECONDS   =   60 * 60 * 24 * THRESHOLD_DAYS
    # seconds of right now
    NOW_SECONDS         =   systime()
}

# This code is processed FOR EACH line of input
{
    FILE_PATH       =   gensub(/Path: ([[:print:]]+).*/, "\\1", "g", $1)
    #UUID_TOKEN      =   $2
    OWNER           =   gensub(/Owner: ([[:alnum:]]+).*/, "\\1", "g", $3)
    #LOCK_CREATED    =   $4
    #EXPIRES         =   $5
    #COMMENT         =   $6

    # skip if owner matches regex
    if (OWNER ~ /kerri|jon|brian|andy|steve|andrew|matthew.nolan|devel|wayne|matty/ ||
        FILE_PATH ~ /UFT\//){
        next
    }

    # get only the timestamp
    # e.g. 2014-04-14 14:09:10
    LOCK_STAMP      =   gensub(/Created: ([[:graph:]]+ [[:graph:]]+) .*/, "\\1", "g", LOCK_CREATED)

    # mktime expected syntax: "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"
    LOCK_SECONDS    =   gensub(/[-:]/," ","g", LOCK_STAMP)

    # if NOW minus LOCK is greater than THRESHOLD :: the lock is old
    if ( (NOW_SECONDS - LOCK_SECONDS) > THRESHOLD_SECONDS ){
        # use the spaces character for string concatenation
        # LOCKS[OWNER]    =   LOCKS[OWNER] "\n\t" FILE_PATH
        LOCKS[OWNER]    =   FILE_PATH "\n" LOCKS[OWNER]
    }

    ++counter
}

END {
    for (i in LOCKS){
        print i
        printf "%s", LOCKS[i] | "sort"
        # MESSAGE = i_OWNER ": you are holding locks on the following files:" LOCKS[i_OWNER]
        # print MESSAGE | "mutt -s '" i_OWNER ": You have old locks in SVN repository' " i_OWNER "@example.com.au"
    }
}
```

### Sample Input

```
Path: /Trunk/Lettus/UFT/30-order-and-invoice/default.cfg
UUID Token: opaquelocktoken:703b9c76-a0c6-4ecd-9078-878382e03572
Owner: matty
Created: 2014-05-22 14:36:14 +1000 (Thu, 22 May 2014)
Expires:
Comment (1 line):


Path: /Trunk/Scanner/Lettus_V2_IntermecVersion/LettusMobile/bin/Release/LettusMobile/Intermec.DataCollection.CF2.xml
UUID Token: opaquelocktoken:4fec94d3-4a19-4366-9efb-c814152a167b
Owner: felipe
Created: 2014-05-28 12:14:56 +1000 (Wed, 28 May 2014)
Expires:
Comment (1 line):


Path: /Trunk/Lettus/UFT/00-lettus-common/Action0/ObjectRepository.bdb
UUID Token: opaquelocktoken:bec7866a-2f39-4a6d-b2fd-4b47ef3cdece
Owner: matty
Created: 2014-05-22 14:36:15 +1000 (Thu, 22 May 2014)
Expires:
Comment (1 line):


Path: /Trunk/Lettus/UFT/30-order-and-invoice/Action2/Resource.mtr
UUID Token: opaquelocktoken:0d1234a3-8a1f-434e-91e8-03315e64b085
Owner: matty
Created: 2014-05-22 14:36:17 +1000 (Thu, 22 May 2014)
Expires:
Comment (1 line):


Path: /Trunk/Lettus/UFT/30-order-and-invoice/Default.xls
UUID Token: opaquelocktoken:28f63d50-3280-4f90-b552-5f297ab8c973
Owner: matty
Created: 2014-05-22 14:36:15 +1000 (Thu, 22 May 2014)
Expires:
Comment (1 line):


Path: /Documents/Software/JDeveloper/oneNote/JDeveloperNotebook/Things to Remember.one
UUID Token: opaquelocktoken:5236cfdf-ab7e-4336-a7b8-98e6db221286
Owner: wayne
Created: 2014-03-14 14:10:40 +1000 (Fri, 14 Mar 2014)
Expires:
Comment (1 line):
```

### Desired Output

```
wayne
/Trunk/aaa
/Trunk/file1
/Trunk/file2
/Trunk/zzz

matty
/Trunk/bbb
/Trunk/file3
/Trunk/file4
/Trunk/zzzzzz
```

and so on.

These are going to be emailed to the users by (for example) piping to `mutt` as you can see near the bottom of my sample script above.

Comment: Please add sample input and desired output

Comment: LOCKS[OWNER] should be an array, and you should call `asort` on the array. Google "sort awk"

Comment: How do we derive the desired output from the sample input? I see no occurrence of aaa or zzz in the input data, so how did it appear in the output? I see a user felipe in the input (as well as wayne and matty). In the input, I see 4 files for matty, and one each for wayne and felipe.  How does this tie up with the sample output?  If the answer is "unrelated", please provide the relevant desired output for the sample input data, because it is hard to know what's wanted otherwise. Also, wayne was listed before matty; is that reverse alphabetic order of user name, or some other sorting criterion.

Comment: Sorry, the output does not match the input, but I showed the *format* of the output that is desired. For each "owner" I want a sorted list of files A-Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just not closing the coprocess: it needs to be signalled that it has all the input it's going to get:

```
for (owner in LOCKS){
    print owner
    printf "%s", LOCKS[owner] | "sort"
    close("sort")
}
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html
and http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html